# How to distribute the binary of my program and archive it

Tags: c, binary, gtk, codeblocks

I made an application with Code::blocks and I was told to distribute the binary of my program in a normal archive and have the user run it but I didn't quite grasp what he meant by that and the other problem I have is that the exectutable generated by code:clocks doesn't work so what can I do ? 
ps : I'm using GTK in my application

Comment: So you have a program that doesn't work, and you want to distribute it but don't know what that means... I'm not sure you could be any more vague.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart the program works but the problem is that the executable generated doesn't work but when i compile and run it from code::blocks it works but when i double click it it doesn't launch

Comment: If the executable doesn't work, your program doesn't work. What would be the point of distributing a binary that won't run? Wasting disk space?

Comment: I swear to God that the problem is with the exutable i'm not kidding here i have to send the project tomorrow but the executable doesn't work but when i compile and run with Code:blocks it runs smoothly the problem is with the executable created i thought it was a pemission problem but it's executale if you want me to send you the peoject and you test it i will just tell me what's the problem i'm having

Comment: Ah okay, now I see your **real** problem: your program only works from within Code::Blocks. That is the question you should have asked the first time instead. Also, if this is for a school assignment, the professor should have told you how to submit your project. Your previous question made it sound like you were trying to release a program to the public, not for a school assignment.

Comment: so how can i fix this problem to make the executable work

Comment: when i tried to run the excutable with the command ./application i get segmentation fault even though that when i ran it in code::blocks i get no problem

Comment: You will need to run your code in a debugger, like gdb, and see where it fails.

Comment: @andlabs But how can it work without any segmentation fault in code::blocks but does outside does this mean that codeblocks ignores this segmentation fault

Comment: No, that most likely means there is a bug in your code somewhere. Segmentation faults are phantom bugs: they often happen under specific circumstances. Does the compiler spit out any warnings? Have you tried running the executable in gdb? The IDE isn't going to solve all your problems, so knowing how to work outside it is going to be important, especially on Linux... other than that, I can't say much else; I don't have any recent resources on the matter :/ Good luck with debugging.

Comment: well i don't know how to use gdb because i don't know how to make a makefile :D

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution finally i just moved the executable from bin/debug to the where there's the code source and it worked like magic